# round number in swift to produce one int at a time in output

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Ok guys, I am in a bit of a dilemma, so I got a collectionview and I am trying to find which image the user is on so i decided to create a variable x which is equal to the collectionviewcontentsize / view.frame.width. Ok so then I made and if statement to check if the image is above image 0. Right now I am just trying to fix it before writing other code. My problem is when I say print(x) it prints 1 like 40 times before the image finally hits 2. Oh and this collection view has a cell with an image that fills most the screen and is horizontal scrolling, with paging enabled. So I was wondering if someone could help me print just one number in the output per image. Here is a good image to see the problem [image]

So in that image I only scrolled to the next image or 1st image (2nd in collectionview) (img 1 is considered 0). Please ask in the comments any question or if you are confused. Thanks guys!

Comment: It is easier if you post actual code rather than a screenshot of the code :)

Comment: So you want which image is currently visible in scrollViewDidScroll Right?

Comment: I wanted to include output

Comment: I am currently on image 1 in that picture

Comment: Each cell has one imageView Right?

Comment: yes Parth that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to hold the current number and print the number only if the number changes. Define the variable at the top of your class:

```
var currentImage = 0
```

Then in your `scrollViewDidScroll`, do the following:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView:UIScrollView) {
    let x = floor(myCollectionView.contetOffset.x / view.frame.width)
    if Int(x) != currentImage {
        currentImage = Int(x)
        print(currentImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: nevermind it worked made sure i put it outside of scrollview func

Comment: ok so why does putting the var currentimage outside of function make such a difference? I will accept as correct answer btw, thanks so much

Comment: Because you define  `currentImage` as 0 each time your code is run otherwise and so, each time `scrollViewDidScroll` is called you set `currentImage` to 0 again if you have it within the method and that means that you always meet the != condition in the method ...